# How to find the largest number from a sharepoint list column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

First time using Sharepoint Lists.
Can a guru please help me if it's possible to set the default value in a column to display the largest number in the column? see screenshots below.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Huu: welcome to Sharepoint.stackexchange.  You can create a view in the list settings and then sort the list by Action Reference, descending.  This default is to show 30 items in the list so not sure that meets your needs